# LINQ: Create a Conditional Where Clause in child list

Tags: c#, linq

I need help to build a "query" using LINQ `where". I'm not getting this alone.

I need to create a conditional clause, but into a child list.

By the way, here is an example.

```
public void Main{
    List<Father> Fathers = getFathers(); 

    //How can I create this clause? 
    Fathers.Where(x=>x.age > 50 && x.ChildrenGirl.Where(y=>y.ID == 5))

}

public class Father{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int age {get; set;}
    public List<ChildGirl> ChildrenGirl  { get; set; }
    public List<ChildBoy> ChildrenBoy { get; set; }
}

public class ChildGirl{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int power {get;set;}
}

public class ChildBoy{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int power {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: You already have a clause, What's wrong with it ? All your Properties are not public, probably you get errors during compilation ?

Comment: By the way, it's LINQ (**L**anguage **IN**tegrated **Q**uery), not LINK

Comment: It's kind of difficult to work with this pseudo-code that doesn't even compile, but I guess something like
`fathers.Where(x => x.age > 50 && x.ChildrenGirl.Any(y => y.ID == 5));`
might solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Any` function to check if at least one exists with condition

```cs
   Fathers.Where(x => x.age > 50 && x.ChildrenGirl.Any(y => y.ID == 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

First make all your properties public.  Nothing will work without that.

You may find using the query comprehension syntax is easier for queries like this.  This is the query you are looking for, using that syntax:

```
 var result = from father in GetFathers()
     from girl in father.ChildrenGirl
     where father.age > 50 && girl.ID == 5
     select father;
```

When you are updating your question, you should provide an implementation of `GetFathers()` that fills up a collection of `Father` objects, each with some children.  I'd have tested my code a lot more if you had done that.